# Sympy custom function

Tags: python, sympy

I noticed, that there is no functions like sech(x) and csch(x).

Is there any way to quickly define them as 1/cosh(x) and 1/sinh(x) respectively?

Also, how can I make sympy to treat arccos as acos?

I'm using parser, so 'cos(pi/2)' is correctly parsed. But I want 'arccos(pi/2)' to be parsed in a similar manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define functions that accomplish your desired behaviour.

```
import sympy

def sech(x):
    return sympy.cosh(x)**(-1)
# sympy.sech = sech

def csch(x):
    return sympy.sinh(x)**(-1)
# sympy.csch = csch

arccos = sympy.acos
```

Originally I showed lines (commented out now) that attach them to the symbol you use when you import sympy.  This is a bad habit called [monkey patching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) and will interfere with any updates to `sympy` that may use those names or other people who may have monkey patched `sympy` elsewhere in the code. It will also make people reading your code think that those attributes were part of the original `sympy` package.

```
y = sympy.symbols('y')
print sech(y)
print csch(y)
print arccos(y)
```

Comment: You can just write `arccos = acos`.

Comment: Don't monkeypatch `sympy.arccos`. Just write `arccos = sympy.cos`.

Comment: Do whatever you like.  I prefer it as written.  It highlights the fact that `arccos` is simply an alias for another sympy function. The origin of a plain old `arccos` is not clear in the line it is written and makes the user track down the `arccos = sympy.acos` line.

Comment: Actually, if you monkeypatch `sympy.arccos`, it does the exact opposite. If someone later sees `sympy.arccos` they will incorrectly believe that SymPy calls the function arccos. Writing `arccos` as a local variable makes it clear that this is your own alias.

Comment: Sorry, @asmeurer, taking a look at your profile I can see why you wouldn't want sympy monkey patched!  I also see the danger inherent in doing it to any imported package. I'll add some discussion to the answer.